# Non progressive verbs. Was seeing, was looking good

Tags: verbs, continuous-aspect

Non progressive verbs are not used in continuous, right?

But what about, for example, sentences like:

> "Gazing absently over the rooftops, it was a few seconds before Harry realised what he **was seeing**." (Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban),

or

> "She **was looking** good" (Rajesh in the "Big bang theory").
>   Can it be concluded, that non progressive verbs actually can be used in Past Continuous?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stative verbs in the continuous form?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187261/stative-verbs-in-the-continuous-form), but I'm convinced there's a better treatment here somewhere. // Ah, I'm happier with ['wanting' or 'want'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110817/wanting-or-want).

Comment: Generally, but not always. Both your examples are fine. In the second, "was looking" has a static, not dynamic, meaning. In the first,  the element "what he was seeing" is an interrogative - in which "what" is direct object - and thus has a dynamic meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that some stative verbs can be used continuously. Sometimes this changes their meaning, or simply refers to a specific period in time, rather than something constant. In the case of TBBT, we might assume that in this particular instance, the person looked (was looking, rather) good.

I am not sure if we can do this same with HP; "was looking at" might be a better choice.

See here for more information: http://www.grammaring.com/state-verbs-and-action-verbs

(apologies for the layout. Can't seem to make the link function work on my phone)