# What are the uses of 'having?'

Tags: grammar, verbs

When I possess something I can say

> I have a pen.

But can I say:

> 1. I am having a pen

As far as I know "be + having" is used when I consume or enjoy something like *I am having breakfast*.

What is the rule when a third person possesses something?

> Murad has a car.

This sentence is correct.

But are these sentences correct:

> 2. Murad is having a car.
> 3. Murad is having his dinner.
> 4. Murad was having his dinner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Wanting" or "want"? (Stative verbs: participial clauses; present continuous usages?)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110817/wanting-or-want-stative-verbs-participial-clauses-present-continuous-usa)

Answer (score 2):

"To have" is never used in the continuous tenses when it has the meaning of "to possess".

- [OALD, 1](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/have_1?q=have) (also have got)
  have something
  (not used in the progressive tenses)
  to own, hold or possess something